# Content slider with lightSlider using Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to create a dynamic content slider using  [LightSlider](http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/) plugin.I have built a script that loads all content from a database table (returning `json` to `HTML`).I want 4 `div`'s of content to be displayed **instead of 6**, like below (6 transactions stored in database table in total)

[image]

What I need is 4 `div`'s per slide to be displayed.Does anyone know how I can do that?Please help.I have already posted about this but I couldn't find out a solution.

Ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'ajax_json.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {get_param: 'value'},
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {

       $.each(data, function(index, item) {
       $('#content-slider').append('<li class="caption"><div class="col-md-3"><div class="item_img"><img src="' +item.image+ '" /></div><div class="item_title">"' +item.title+ '"</div><div class="item_descr">'+ item.description +'</div></div></li>');


                });
            }
        });
```

and `HTML` output:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="item">
           <ul id="content-slider" class="content-slider">
           </ul>
        </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and this is for slider creation:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#content-slider").lightSlider({
                item: 4,
                pager: false,
                autoWidth: false,
                slideMargin: 0
            });
```

Comment: Your seems ok. The item param works for me

Comment: Can you provide the result in fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the default item value in your lightslider.js file and remove the item value in your slider creation method.

I have a similar slider that I'm working on and it display 3 items per slide as I want it. I dont have the item value on my slider creation method. When I change the item value in lightslider.js file it will change the number of items in the slide.

Here is the start of my lightslider.js file.

```
(function ($, undefined) {
'use strict';
var defaults = {
    item: 3,
    autoWidth: false,
    slideMove: 1,
    slideMargin: 10,
    addClass: '',
    ..............
```